# Sort First Section and Last Section of Text File Line into Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, list, file, dictionary

I have a text file that's formatted like this:

```
#fname @@ mname @@ lname #
john @@ apple @@ smith 1
jane @@ banana @@ doe 2
franklin @@ delano @@ roosevelt 3
thomas @@ woodrow @@ wilson 4
```

What's the best way to put fname and lname into a dictionary but exclude mname? My expected outcome is that I'll later be able to find out how common peoples names are but I can manage on my own. Assuming that lnames are unique.

If this violates the rules could someone smarter than point me in the right direction of what to study. The stuff I've read wasn't helpful, and I wasn't getting anywhere.

Thanks

Here's the code I tried:

```
a_dictionary = {}
a_file = open("list_of_names.txt")
for line in a_file:
    key, value = line.split('@@')
    fname = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"
    lname = r"[A-Z][a-z]+"
    re.findall(fname + lname)
    fname = line.split('@@')[0]
    lname = line.split('@@')[3]
    a_dictionary[key] = value

print(a_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example file, you can:

1. Read the file
2. Split each line by `' @@ '`
3. Pick the two fields that you want, [0] and [2]
4. Make a tuple out of that (or use those two fields as you need to...)

Example:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    data=[(e[0],e[2].rstrip()) for e in (line.split(' @@ ') for line in f_in)]

>>> data
[('#fname', 'lname #'), ('john', 'smith 1'), ('jane', 'doe 2'), ('franklin', 'roosevelt 3'), ('thomas', 'wilson 4')]
```

Then you can use `data` for analysis as you choose.